# Haskell: Why are my environment variables not available when running my project under cabal?

Tags: haskell, environment-variables, cabal

Does anyone know how to define environment variables to be accessed by a program run with cabal?

I want to define system environment variables that are available to my program, e.g. via [System.Environment](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html)'s 'getEnv' function. The variables are available to 'getEnv' in ghci, but not to a program run with cabal ('cabal run').

I define my environment variables as:

```
$ export myvar=MYVALUE
```

Accessing them works in ghci:

```
Prelude System.Environment> getEnv "myvar"
"MYVALUE"
```

However, similarly using 'getEnv' in my program and running with 'cabal run' gives the error:

```
getEnv: does not exist (no environment variable)
```

Somehow my program is not finding them when run via cabal. I tried placing the 'export' statements in my .bash_profile and restarting my terminal. But this gave the same issue of working in ghci and giving that error when run with cabal.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only executed for login shells; try adding it to your `.bashrc`.  Does the verbosity flag tell you anything?  I see the calls at the end of https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/cabal-install/Distribution/Client/Run.hs and `rawSystemExitWithEnv` in https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/Utils.hs

Comment: Just to check, you are running `cabal run` from the same shell as `ghci`, right? What OS is this?

Comment: for the record the OS is macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I realized that this was just due to a stupid mistake by me.

My program used a couple different environment variables, some of which were being successfully read -- the error was due to a missing one which I hadn't tested in ghci.

So the issue was due to not testing all the variables, a silly mistake, but thanks for the comments anyway as they were helpful in diagnosing the issue.